# Проблема с FileOutputStream

Tags: android

Нужно сохранить массив.

```
public void setFolders(ArrayList<ModelFolder> s) {

    try {
        FileOutputStream fog = ctx.openFileOutput("folder", ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream
        (fog) ;

        os.writeObject(s);
        os.flush();
        os. close () ;
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
    }
}
```

Не хочет сохранять, хотя ArrayList сохраняет. В чем можете быть проблема?

Comment: ModelFolder **implemets** Serializable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в непонимании работы классов, которые вы используете. Как уже написал человек выше **ObjectOutputStream** используется для сериализации,  а для этого необходимо чтобы обьект,  который вы сериализуете должен имплементировать интерфейс **Serializaible**. Если вы просто хотите сохранить в файл, то вам необходимо использовать обёртку **BufferedOutputStream**